# simple way to delete cookies in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a cookie and use it like this.inside a `document.ready`

```
 document.cookie = $('#rdb1').attr("id");
 check = document.cookie.split(';');
 flag = check[0];
```

But unable to erase cookies.I found this function.

```
function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain ) 
{
   if ( Get_Cookie( name ) )
   document.cookie=name+"="+((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
                                   ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

on [javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie).But unable to use this function in my situation.Any idea how to deal with this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), you might want to try just setting the cookie to null, like this:

```
$.cookie("name", null);
```

There was a similar question about it found here: [jquery, delete cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies) .

> **Note:** when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie.

To set the path for a cookie, you could use something like this:

```
$.cookie("name", null, { path: '/' });
```

Comment: what a `name` stands for in my situation?

Comment: In your case, "name" is whatever your cookie's name is. :)

Comment: I put a link to jQuery cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) in the answer, as well, just in case you need to get the `jquery.cookie.js` file to make this work!

Comment: i modify the question.i use cookies like this.Again i am confusing what is the name stands for?

Comment: It is the name you want to use for your cookie. It's easier to use the jQuery cookie plugin for creating the cookie.  To create a cookie, you would just write something like: `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');`  In that example, the cookie's name is `'the_cookie'`.  Then... to delete that cookie... you would just use `$.cookie('the_cookie', null);`

Answer (score 0):

I use this jquery plugin (very simple =P).

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie