# Destroying Jquery Cookie from Code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have an application which has a Jquery cookie that counts down from 10 minutes, is there a way of destroying the Jquery cookie from the code behind, I think I already know the answer to this which is you cant? but im just curious if someone has ever done this?

```
$.cookie('time', '0:00', { expires: 1 });
```

The below sets the cooking to expire in one day

Comment: question repeated [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies)

Comment: The question is different from the one you have linked! im asking how to destroy it from code behind! the link you have posted is discussing how to destroy the cookie with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy a cookie by setting the value to null:

```
$.cookie("time", null);
```