# Destroy jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, json, cookies, append

I have a script which allows to save input value as a list: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6CN/7/)

So now Im trying to make an event which will delete a certain list if clicked on, of course the cookie should be destroyed. So I tried:

```
$('.jq-text li').click(function(e) {

$.cookie("myDemoCookie", null);

 });
```

This should destroy the cookie but it doesn't...

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies

Comment: Yes I saw that, its what I based myy code on. IF you look it is exactly the same.....(but it doesnt work)

Comment: I pointed to that question because in the answer it specifically says it is not correct and the below answer actually suggests about the path of the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your jsfiddle code, you are creating cookie with a path, so you'll have to specify `path` when deleting cookie.

Make sure you have read [documentation of $.cookie](http://moskah.nl/jquery.cookie.js).

```
@example $.cookie('the_cookie', null);

@desc Delete a cookie by passing null as value. 
 Keep in mind that you have to use the same path 
 and domain used when the cookie was set.`
```

**Try following code:**

```
$.cookie('myDemoCookie', null, { path: '/' });
```

Comment: I tried that `$.cookie('myDemoCookie',JSON.stringify(values),{expires: 7, path: '/' }, null);` Doesnt work

Comment: Thanks:) do you have any idea why this doesn't work     `$(this).cookie('myDemoCookie', null, { path: '/' });` Because it seems your code deletes all the list and not the one clicked on

Comment: I think you do not need to delete cookie this time, you need to update. I have done that for you :) check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/dx6CN/9/

Comment: Thanks for sticking around:) Your code is not working 100% but I think its because of JsFiddle(does not handle cookie very well) not because of code

Comment: may be its browser compatibility issue, I was testing with chrome.

Comment: I work with chrome to, but I experienced cookie problems with JsFiddle in other coding.