# Deleting cookie through jQuery cookie script

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, cookies

I have a website with 3 html files:

Language selection: `media/index.html`

EN page: `media/en/index.html`

CN page: `media/cn/index.html`

Site files: `media/site/`

I create a cookie via this script, when a visitor selects a language on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var url = '';
        var en_page = 'en';
        var cn_page = 'cn';

        if ($.cookie('default_page') != null) {
            if (window.location.href != url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page')) {
                window.location.href = url + '/' + $.cookie('default_page');
            }
        }

        $('#enlink').click(function () {
            $.cookie('default_page', en_page, {expires: 999, path: '/', domain: 'mywebsite.com'});
        });

        $('#cnlink').click(function () {
            $.cookie('default_page', cn_page, {expires: 999, path: '/', domain: 'mywebsite.com'});
        });

    });

</script>

    ....
    ....

    <a href="cn/index.html" id="cnlink">CN</a>
    <br>
<a href="en/index.html" id="enlink">EN</a>
```

This successfully creates a cookie called "default_page" with a value of either "cn" or "en", then redirects user to `mywebsite.com/cn` or `mywebsite.com/en` on subsequent visits. This all works fine.

However, I'm unable to **delete** this cookie. I need to delete this cookie whenever the user clicks a link to change language in `media/en/index.html` or `media/cn/index.html` (ie my actual website, not the language selection page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function deletecookie(){
        alert('delete');
        $.cookie('default_page', null, {path: '/', domain: 'mywebsite.com'});
    }

</script>

....
....

<a href="../index.html" onclick="deletecookie()">
    Change language
</a>
```

But this is not working, the moment I click "change language", it still redirects me back to the same page (since the cookie still exists), so I'm unable to access the language page (`media/index.html`). The function is being called, as I get the alert box, but I checked my browser, which is Firefox, and the cookie `mywebsite/default_page` is still there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try the removeCookie function provided by the plugin itself? $.removeCookie('default_page', { path: '/' });

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
$.cookie('default_page', null, {path: '/', domain: 'mywebsite.com'});
```

to this

```
$.cookie('default_page', null);
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference ? this is an explanation I got from here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7633502/1100019
"It is the problem of misunderstand of cookie. Browsers recognize cookie values for not just keys also compare the options path & domain. So Browsers recognize different value which cookie values that key is 'name' with server setting option(path='/'; domain='mydomain.com') and key is 'name' with no option."

Comment: It might not, but it's just a suggestion.