# remove cookie using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a little demo page to show the effect of a website depending on different user cookies.
Then I set the `click()` function of some `div` to use the plugin jquery.cookie.js which provides 2 functions:

```
$.cookie('name', 'val')
$.removeCookie('name')
```

after I called `$.removeCookie()`, I call `window.open('new page')` since I need to go to the content. but httpliveheader always shows that it's not removing the cookie in question.

Comment: Put in an alert after the `$.removeCookie` to make sure it's being called without any errors.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies

Comment: Can you provide your code and/or a link to a JSFiddle?

Comment: `$.removeCookie()` requires an argument... (based on code you've posted, if you have posted just function name it is unlikely to get meaningful help). Please consider debugging and posting error messages if you see any.

Comment: technically it is impossible to actually delete a cookie, jQuery just sets the expire date to a time in the past, if that helps at all

Comment: thanks guys, I did go through firebug and saw that the $.removeCookie() line is called.

Comment: I did the following :    document.cookie = "buyerId=11";//";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;";  but ended up getting "Cookie: buyerId=oldValue; someOtherCookie; buyerId=11 " in httpliveheader

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it, it was because the cookie set by my backend code and front end JS are in different path.

my java spring MVC controller has an access path of /MyPath/Blah/  in the code I just did

httpServletResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("something", "something"));

this turns out to default to the path where the code sits under , i.e. /MyPath/Blah/

but the  JS sets something like $.cookie("something", "somevalue"), it goes to root. that's why I am seeing 2 different values in httpLiveHeader dump. unfortunately the path thing is controlled by browser, so it doesn't show up on liveheader dump. I only found this after I inspected the "remove cookie" window in mozilla

Answer (score -1):

//for example :

```
document.cookie = "cookie_name=" + encodeURIComponent(cookie_value) +

                          "; expires=" +  expires.toGMTString() +

                          "; path=/";
```

you need to set PATH.

Comment: path is optional in cookies  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie Also OP is using jQuery cookie plugin that knows if you don't set path how to handle it

Comment: i know,you can't use jQuery cookie,need to rewrite.you can look at here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html ,about path in cookie