# How to Remove a Cookie on Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Good day,

I'm trying to remove the cookie when submitting the form, but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
$("form").submit(function()
{

  var cookiePath = "Table_Rows-"+$(location).attr('pathname');
  alert(cookiePath);
  $.removeCookie(cookiePath);
}
```

Even if I delete all cookies using these code, it still won't work:

```
 $("form").submit(function()
{
  for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);
}
```

Im setting my data to be save on a cookie via onbeforeuload function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
{
storeRowData();
console.log("cookie saved!");
};
```

and here's my StoreData() js

```
var storeRowData = function () {
 var data = []; 
$('#tblItemList tbody>tr').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),

        pId = $this.find("#itemId").val();
        pname = $this.find('input.itemSearch').attr("value"),
        desc = $this.find(".description").val(),
        quant = $this.find(".qty").val(),
        rowId = $this.find(".rowId").val(),
        deleted = $this.find(".hidden-deleted-id").val(),
        price = $this.find(".price").val();

    var temp = { 
        productName: pname, 
        itemId:pId,
        description: desc,
        quantity: quant, 
        price: price,
        deleted:deleted, 
        rowId: rowId };
    data.push(temp);
});
var cookiePath = 'Table_Rows-'+$(location).attr('pathname');
$.cookie(cookiePath, JSON.stringify(data), {expires: 7});
}
```

then im checking if cookie was set on the page on document.ready function:

```
if($.cookie('Table_Rows-'+$(location).attr('pathname'))){
loadCookieData();
$(".qty, .price").bind("keyup change", calculate);
}
else{
addRow(0);
}
```

and my loadCookieData()

```
var cookiePath = 'Table_Rows-'+$(location).attr('pathname');
//console.log("loadCookieData:"+cookiePath);
temp = $.cookie(cookiePath);
var parseData = JSON.parse(temp);
//console.log(parseData);
var html ='';



for (i in parseData) {

    subTotal = parseData[i].quantity*parseData[i].price;
    var st = new Number(subTotal);
    var sub = st.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');

    html+= (some html code to replace here)   
 }
$("#tblItemList tbody").html(html);

  for (i in parseData){
  var inputBox = "#itemName"+parseData[i].rowId;
  $(inputBox).select2(sOptions);
}
calculate(); 
}
```

Is there something wrong with my current code ??

Can anyone tell me how to properly do it please?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the `cookiePath` the cookie name?

Comment: Is the alert showing up or no?

Comment: yes it is the cookieName and alert's also showing @VIDesignz

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies

Comment: Note: some cookie can not be modified/deleted if you are not on the same subdomain/domain or path as the cookie was set for, if i remember corectly.

Comment: @Endless But Im still on the same page, anyway thanks for the tip. (y)

Comment: sometimes simple javascript is just easier `$(location).attr('pathname')` -> `location.pathname`

Comment: @Endless I see the point :) , will that affect the behavior my code as well? I mean if Ill use simple javascript instead of jquery, will it make difference?

Comment: Could it be that you are deleting the cookie and setting it back onbeforeunload?

Comment: hmmm.. I guess that whats happening, yeah I think submit will be override by the onbeforeunload right? can you please suggest on what should I do so I can actually delete it I mean override that onbeforeunload? Im setting it to onbeforeunload so the data will still remain even I do refresh or redirect to other page and then go back.

Comment: My suggestion would be not to use onbeforeunload at all sense its has some issues in some browsers or versions of browsers. i think opera didn't even had it until they changed to webkit

if it isn't a problem for you, you can do either `onbeforeunload = null` or `storeRowData = $.noop`

Comment: finally solved it! thank you very much for seeing that onbeforeunload thing! I did by adding `window.onbeforeunload = false` on submit funtion and it worked! did it because of your help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my answer sience its not a restricting problem anymore

```
document.cookie = cookiePath + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

Comment: will I add this code on my .submit function? sorry Im a little confuse :3

Comment: This is just a test to see if you manage to delete all your cookies. you can run it anywhere console, the submit event

Comment: This isen't going to delete just that one cookie you wanna delete. just too see if it is possible

Comment: Your code did delete the cookies.. can you please customize so I can specifically delete a cookie please? thank you very much for the help!

Comment: actually did tried putting this code: `for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);` on `document.ready` and it also worked! also deleted all cookies as well. my only problem here is that it wont work when im putting it on `submit function`