# delete cookie in jQuery on page refresh in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, laravel-5.1

I am trying to delete a cookie on page refresh but I am unable to achieve it. I have done this so far

```
//delete the cookie on page refresh
window.onunload = unloadPage;
function unloadPage()
{
    $.removeCookie('count', { path: '/' });
}
```

This code is at the top of my `js` file.
I have also tried answers here at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/jquery-delete-cookies)

**UPDATE**
I am using laravel and I am using this code to set the cookie

```
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('count', $count));
```

Comment: And do you have a plugin called `removeCookie` ?

Comment: yes, https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie @adeneo

Comment: I suspect you're having trouble deleting the cookie in javascript because it's set to httpOnly.  You can check easily in the chrome inspector on the resources tab.  There will be a check mark in the HTTP column of the cookie list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had to go this way to delete the cookie

```
//delete the cookie on page refresh
    $.ajax({
        url:'remove-cookie',
        method:'post',
        success: function(){
            console.log("cookie deleted");
        }
    });
```

and in my controller method

```
/**
     * delete the count cookie
     */
    public function destroyCookie(){
        $cookie = Cookie::forget('count');
        $response = new Response($cookie);
        $response->withCookie($cookie);

        return $response;
    }
```

Route is

```
Route::post('remove-cookie', 'DonnerController@destroyCookie');
```

I hope it may help someone working with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.cookie = 'count=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Comment: this is not deleting the cookie unfortunately.

Comment: btw cookie is being set by php and  I want to delete that in jQuery

Comment: Doesn't matter from where is set the cookie, still is in client-side - Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the unload event, because every time you refresh, every script that is included in your header will be executed from top to bottom.

Because of this, all you have to do is make a simple check at the top of your script, to verify that the current URL is the same as before, if you want to make sure that the page really was refreshed.

Here's an example (not tested):

```
if (document.referrer == window.location.href) {
    // The page was refreshed.
}
```

Hope this helps!