# How to remove a cookie objects array in $each loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code for cookie object. i want to delete an object which $each loop. How can i do that .

```
    var obj =
    {
    'deviceid': deviceId,
    'full': cookiefull,
    'stacked': istoggle

    };

var cookieDevObjArray = GetCookieDevObjArray();
if (cookieDevObjArray.length > 0) {
    
    var decoded = $.parseJSON($.cookie("cookieDevObjArray"));
    $.each(decoded, function (index, value) {
        if (value.deviceid == deviceId) {
           //how to delete object from array//
            value.deviceId={expire :-1}
        }
    });
}


$.cookie("cookieDevObjArray", JSON.stringify(obj), { expires: 30 });
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671659/how-to-delete-a-cookie-using-jquery) answer ?